# Improving the speed of preprocessing

Tags: gensim, lemmatization

Following code is used to preprocess text with a custom lemmatizer function:

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess, lemmatize
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
STOPWORDS = list(STOPWORDS)

def preprocessor(s):
    result = []
    for token in lemmatize(s, stopwords=STOPWORDS, min_length=2):
        result.append(token.decode('utf-8').split('/')[0])
    return result

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/dqKFZ12m')

%%time
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split([preprocessor(x) for x in data.text],
                                                    data.label, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
#10.8 seconds
```

Question: 
**Can the speed of the lemmatization process be improved?**

On a large corpus of about 80,000 documents, it currently takes about two hours. The `lemmatize()` function seems to be the main bottleneck, as a gensim function such as `simple_preprocess` is quite fast.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refactor your code to make it easier to time each portion separately. `lemmatize()` might be part of your bottleneck, but other significant contributors *might* also be: (1) composing large documents, one-token-at-a-time, via list `.append()`; (2) the utf-8 decoding.

Separately, the gensim `lemmatize()` relies on the `parse()` function from the `Pattern` library; you could try an alternative lemmatization utility, like those in NLTK or Spacy.

Finally, as lemmatization may be an inherently costly operation, and it might be the case that the same source data gets processed many times in your pipeline, you might want to engineer your process so that the results are re-written to disk, then re-used on subsequent runs – rather than always done "in-line".